# Issue with sql filtering parent_id, id and sort

Tags: sql, sorting, filter

I want to filter my data according to 3 columns.

- parent_id
- id
- sort

Example base BDD :

```
id | parent_id | sort | text
-----------------------------
1  |    NULL   |  3   |  D
2  |     10    |  0   |  AA
3  |    NULL   |  1   |  B
4  |     10    |  2   |  AB
5  |     3     |  0   |  BA
6  |     8     |  0   |  CA
7  |     3     |  2   |  BC
8  |    NULL   |  2   |  C
9  |     3     |  1   |  BB
10 |    NULL   |  0   |  A
11 |     1     |  0   |  DA
```

I want to get this result :

```
id | parent_id | sort | text
-----------------------------
10 |    NULL   |  0   |  A
2  |     10    |  0   |  AA
4  |     10    |  2   |  AB
3  |    NULL   |  1   |  B
5  |     3     |  0   |  BA
9  |     3     |  1   |  BB
7  |     3     |  2   |  BC
8  |    NULL   |  2   |  C
6  |     8     |  0   |  CA
1  |    NULL   |  3   |  D
11 |     1     |  0   |  DA
```

I try with a `COALESCE` function without success : `SELECT * FROM menu ORDER BY COALESCE(parent_id, id) ASC, parent_id ASC, sort ASC`.

I think that there is an order logic to be set by priority with `COALESCE` function... I'm not sure...

- Step 1 : sort by parent_id ASC if IS NULL
- Step 2 : sort by parent_id ASC if IS NOT NULL

Data for live test : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ed850/1

**SOLUTION (Work for symfony with doctrine)**

Thank [@quadzz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5720797/quadzz) and others for your answers

```
SELECT test.*, 
       ( CASE 
           WHEN test.parent_id IS NULL THEN test.sort 
           ELSE test_1.sort 
         END ) AS test1, 
       ( CASE 
           WHEN test.parent_id IS NULL THEN 1 
           ELSE 0 
         END ) AS test2 
FROM   test AS test 
       LEFT JOIN test AS test_1 
              ON ( test_1.id = test.parent_id )
ORDER  BY test1 ASC, 
          test2 DESC, 
          test.sort ASC
```

Live result : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ed850/4

Comment: You only ever have one level of hierarchy? (any row is *either* a parent or a child, never both forming grandparent or deeper relationships)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should do the trick:

Prepare data:

```
if object_id('tempdb..#t1') is not null drop table #t1
create table #t1
(
    id int,
    parent_id int,
    sort int,
    text varchar(10)
)

insert into #t1
values
(1,null,3,'d'),
(2,10,0,'aa'),
(3,null,1,'d'),
(4,10,2,'d'),
(5,3,0,'d'),
(6,8,0,'d'),
(7,3,2,'d'),
(8,null,2,'d'),
(9,3,1,'d'),
(10,null,0,'d'),
(11,1,0,'d')
```

And the sorting itself:

```
select *
from #t1 t1
order by 
    case when t1.parent_id is null then t1.sort
    else (
        select sort
        from #t1 innert1
        where innert1.id = t1.parent_id
        ) end,
    case when parent_id is null then 1 end desc,
    sort
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work.

```
ORDER BY COALESCE(parent_id, id), 
case when parent_id is null then 1 else 2 end, 
sort
```

Answer (score 0):

It actually appears you need a self-join to the properly ranked order of the parent ID first.  To do so, I am running a query using RANK() OVER, but only for parent_ID = null for the top-most records you want (such as menu, or other hierarchical org chart).

```
select id, sort, rank() over( order by sort ) as xRank
   from YourTable
   where parent_id is null
```

The Rank() and order by will return the following results

```
id   sort   xRank
10   0      1
 3   1      2
 8   2      3
 1   3      4
```

Now, you know the top-most proper order that all additional details need to be.
Now, take and join your entire table back to this result on either the ID = ranked ID OR the Parent ID = ranked ID.  So this way all the NULL records that were the basis of the query are included in the result to.

The primary sort is based on the ParentRanked pre-query's xRANK column, then based on the normal sort after that.  The resulting query is...

```
select 
        YT.*,
        ParentRank.id as ParentRankID,
        ParentRank.xRank
    from
        YourTable YT
        JOIN ( select 
                    id, 
                    sort, 
                    rank() over( order by sort ) as xRank
                from 
                    YourTable
                where 
                    parent_id is null ) ParentRank
            on YT.parent_id = ParentRank.id
            OR YT.id = ParentRank.id
    order by
        ParentRank.xRank,
        YT.Sort;
```